# how to add a day to date column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanna add a day to all cells of this dataframe:

```
value       B   N   S      date   
date                    
2020-12-31  1   11  0   2020-12-31  
2021-01-01  3   80  0   2021-01-01  
2021-01-02  4   99  0   2021-01-02  
2021-01-03  3   78  0   2021-01-03  
2021-01-04  0   50  0   2021-01-04
```

to make it like this:

```
value       B   N   S      date   
date                    
2020-12-31  1   11  0   2021-01-01  
2021-01-01  3   80  0   2021-01-02  
2021-01-02  4   99  0   2021-01-03  
2021-01-03  3   78  0   2021-01-04  
2021-01-04  0   50  0   2021-01-05
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily convert to datetime to add a [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

```
df['date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
                .add(pd.DateOffset(days=1))
                .dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') # optional
               )
```

Output:

```
         value  B    N  S         date
0   2020-12-31  1   11  0   2021-01-01
1   2021-01-01  3   80  0   2021-01-02
2   2021-01-02  4   99  0   2021-01-03
3   2021-01-03  3   78  0   2021-01-04
4   2021-01-04  0   50  0   2021-01-05
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']).add(pd.offsets.Day(1))
df
```

```
    value   B   N   S   date
0   2020-12-31  1   11  0   2021-01-01
1   2021-01-01  3   80  0   2021-01-02
2   2021-01-02  4   99  0   2021-01-03
3   2021-01-03  3   78  0   2021-01-04
4   2021-01-04  0   50  0   2021-01-05
```